# Display 2 weeks in jQuery FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Been looking around for a way to display only the current week and the next week in the month view for [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). So far it looks like it was suggested as a feature for an upcoming version, but in the meantime, has anyone been able to hack it in?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Doomsday's suggestion, I was able to create a custom view that shows 2 weeks, starting on the current week. You are changing the visible start date to today's date and changing the row count to 2.

```
function TwoWeeksView(element, calendar) {
var t = this;

// exports
t.render = render;


// imports
BasicView.call(t, element, calendar, 'month');
var opt = t.opt;
var renderBasic = t.renderBasic;
var formatDate = calendar.formatDate;



function render(date, delta) {
    if (delta) {
        addMonths(date, delta);
        date.setDate(1);
    }
    var start = cloneDate(date, true);
    start.setDate(1);
    var end = addMonths(cloneDate(start), 1);

    //var visStart = cloneDate(start);
    var visStart = date;

    var visEnd = cloneDate(end);
    var firstDay = opt('firstDay');
    var nwe = opt('weekends') ? 0 : 1;
    if (nwe) {
        skipWeekend(visStart);
        skipWeekend(visEnd, -1, true);
    }

    addDays(visStart, -((visStart.getDay() - Math.max(firstDay, nwe) + 7) % 7));
    addDays(visEnd, (7 - visEnd.getDay() + Math.max(firstDay, nwe)) % 7);
    var rowCnt = Math.round((visEnd - visStart) / (DAY_MS * 7));

    if (opt('weekMode') == 'fixed') {
        addDays(visEnd, (6 - rowCnt) * 7);
        //rowCnt = 6;
        rowCnt = 2;
    }
    t.title = formatDate(start, opt('titleFormat'));
    t.start = start;
    t.end = end;
    t.visStart = visStart;
    t.visEnd = visEnd;
    renderBasic(6, rowCnt, nwe ? 5 : 7, true);
}
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could create a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) of this solution? This is _exactly_ what I'm trying to do right now but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Michael I got this working for me. I needed this exact solution as well. This is probably a little late for you, but the big thing I noticed here is that the fcViews object was not updated with the twoweek view as to be available for use.

You need to add:

`fcViews.twoweek = TweoweekView;

function TwoweekView( element, calendar ) {`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution is it to implement your custom view.

Put in a new JS your own defined view :

```
$.fullCalendar.views.twoweeks = TwoWeeksView;
function TwoWeeksView(element, calendar) {
    // copy code from fullcalendar.js line 1960
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, but it's good to note that you'd need to add additional code if you want the arrows to skip to the next two weeks to work (or any other functionality over and above the just showing two weeks of the calendar.)

That said, this is THE approach you need to use to create additional views for JqueryFullCalendar. Don't bother wasting your time using JQuery to manipulate the created calendar, as it's a complete shitshow.

Comment: see the docs in newer versions for an easy way to do in the options

Answer (score 7):

The proper answer for fullCalendar 2 is to modify the basicWeek view as explained in the documentation:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        views: {
            basicWeek: {
                type: 'basic',
                duration: {weeks: 2},
                rows: 2
            }
        }
    }
```

There. Simple :)

Comment: I've been looking for days for this solution.  THIS is the one to use.

Answer (score 2):

please see here for further information on this fullcalendar custom view

[Jquery FullCalendar 2 week view Next prev buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708621/jquery-fullcalendar-2-week-view-next-prev-buttons)

Answer (score 1):

Answer will be to display two calendars, one with the current week, and another with the week after.

I suggest you to hack what I've done on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Doomsday/M3YP3/1/

Comment: Not really what I was going for. I need a month view that only shows 2 weeks, similar to how Basecamp does it on the dashboard. http://i.imgur.com/tJRWi.png

Comment: Sorry I didn't read "in the month view". See my another answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version now makes it even easier (v2.2.6)

you can also checkout this git where there is a custom twoweek view, that moves 1 week (or whatever option it set to) at a time with the next/prev buttons.

https://github.com/marc-gist/fullcalendar

edit: the gist seems to no longer work with other version of fullcalendar; but look at the docs for an easy week view setup via option values.