# How to make the fullcalendar for only two months?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to display ONLY two months in the calendar, namely July and August. All the other months should be hidden, for example the next month or previous month button should be disabled.

Also I need this calendar only for display purpose, it should not be editable.

And only the dates where events are found in the database should be highlighted, and when the user hovers over that highlighted date he should get to see the details of the event in a small popup.

Is this possible with full calendar?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the previous and next buttons with jQuery when the DOM is ready with:

```
$('td.fc-header-left').empty();
```

or `fc-header-right` if you have the buttons on the right.

As for displaying just July and August, you could either create two `fullCalendar` or create a custom view yourself as answered (albeit showing 2 weeks instead of specific months) - [Display 2 weeks in jQuery FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420200/display-2-weeks-in-jquery-fullcalendar)

**Edit:** Creating 2 separate `fullCalendar`s fixed on the months you need seems to be the easiest option.

Comment: I was wondering if this could be done in the fullcalendar.js---- initially use your code to disable the previous month button...then Go to the event that is triggered when the arrow to the next month is clicked..in that event add a new line of code that you suggested but to remove the next month button...So when it goes to the next month it wont be able to go to the month after that...it will just have a previous button...I hope this can be done..If yes can you please tell me which function is called in the fullcalendar.js on the next month event......

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DatePicker of JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) .

There you can also set a minDate and maxDate:

```
        $(function ()
        {
            $('#DateTextBox').datepicker({
                maxDate: '+1m',
                minDate: '-1m',
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });
        });
```

As example maxdate: Set a maximum selectable date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +1w'), or null for no limit.

In this way you can have a "just 2 months calendar". About readonly calendar you might implement a div that through an higher z-index value overlays the jQuery calendar, making it unselectable, but this however would prevent you from select the single dates.

For what you need, I guess the easiest way would be to extend the plugin itself.

Comment: When anyone puts a negative vote, he/she could at least provide a reason why. At least other developers (and the contributor) have a chance to understand the reason...

Comment: Negative vote because, here we are searching for fullcalendar but you are giving suggestion of datepicker