# Any plugin for grid calendar in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Is there any calendar plugin that show the "months" days in a single row or list?
I need to create a grid like this
[image]

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://fullcalendar.io/ it will certainly require some customization such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420200/display-2-weeks-in-jquery-fullcalendar

Comment: I am currently working on it.
But it requires a lot of customization.

Comment: It looks so but I don't know any plugin matching your requirements out-of-the-box. If you find any that is please let us know :)

Answer (score 0):

wdCalendar might work for you

http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-events-calendar-wdcalendar/

Comment: Something that uses angular JS

Answer (score 0):

Found one [Angular scheduler](https://doc.daypilot.org/scheduler/angularjs/)
Its good, you can extend an event by dragging the bar.
Add events delete events
Functionality for right click is already there.