# Using month view, move week by week instead of month by month

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar v2.2.5 and I would like to navigate *week by week* instead of *month by month* when the calendar is using the *month view*.

I see that the function used to navigate forward is [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/next/) but I wasn't able to figure a way to change this behaviour.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried using `defaultView: 'agendaWeek',`? If the calendar is displayed with agenda week, the next and previous will move to the next and previous week.

Comment: @milz Thank you for your response. I have tried what you mentioned but didn't work. It still moves month by month on the 'month' view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, as stated on [`prev`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/prev/) and [`next`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/next/) documentation:

> If the calendar is in month view, will move the calendar back/forward one month.
>
> If the calendar is in basicWeek or agendaWeek, will move the calendar back/forward one week.
>
> If the calendar is in basicDay or agendaDay, will move the calendar back/forward one day.

If you want to change the how that works, you'll need to use a [`Custom view`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/), based on the month view. Something like:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'customMonth',
    views: {
        customMonth: {
            type: 'month',
            duration: {weeks: 1}
        }
    }
});
```

Basically, you "create" a `customMonth` view (which is the default view), based on the `month` view and the [duration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Duration/) of this is one week.
I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/milz/s99r7bux/) where you can see this working.

Full disclosure: This solution was found based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31507461/908174).