# Fullcalendar using week view, navigate month by month instead of week by week

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am using *fullcalendar* to implement a schedule for a school where the classes are in specific days for the entire month, for example a class can be on **TTH** or **MWF**, **TWTH** etc.

I am trying to implement a week view but I want to navigate month by month so I don't have to display the same class every specific day on the entire month (on month view). Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215588/using-month-view-move-week-by-week-instead-of-month-by-month) I tried to implement the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
defaultView: 'customWeek',
views: {
    customWeek: {
        type: 'week',
        duration: {months: 1}
    }
}
});
```

but this implementation did not force the view to start on the beginning of the month, so if I navigate through the calendar the next view will start on the second day of the month or the third, or sometimes on the last day of the previous month.

I also tried to make it work with CSS on month view so it looks like a week view:

```
.fc-day-top .fc-day-number{
   display: none;
}

.fc td {
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
  border-top: 0 !important;
}

.fc-head {
  border-top: 1px solid black !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}
.fc-body{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

but I lost the time slots at the beginning of the calendar and the events are stuck at the top of it and they look bad.

[image: calendar]

So I am searching for the best approach to complete this task.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? You need a default date like now()?

Comment: i want to show the classes taken for a specific month in a week view, and allow the user to navigate month by month( not week by week)

Comment: You mean the user of week view is different from the user of month view? what i mean is when the user login to your system. or it is only one role of user.

Comment: one role of user? `i want to show the classes taken for a specific month in a week view, and allow the user to navigate month by month( not week by week)`

Comment: I think you need to have one or more user role here. So that you are freely can give the specific view of its user. The role of scheduler, and its viewer.. or the approval if it has.

Comment: So you want a week view for the first week of the month and jump straight to the first week of th next month on navigation, right?

Comment: no (sorry for not being clear), in short words. i want to navigate month by month in a week view. while the starting day is always monday

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes indeed

Comment: I guess you are trying to customize the full calendar default code. You want the week view but the content is per month? How come.. every week has always an specific month... good luck.

Comment: @reds lets assume that the data is always in the first week so i only want to display the first week but when the next and prev button are clicked i want to navigate a full month.

Comment: @George: You only want the week which contain the 1st day of the month? Or the first full week on the calendar? --- I think I have something for you... ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it would be great if i can display the first full week.
thank you for your time :)

Comment: I made both options... (I had already did the first when I taught you might want a full week) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That one was fun! So the trick is to hide the `.fc-week` rows we don't want to see in a month view. Then, we don't have to mess with the normal navigation.

To do this, we have to target which row we want to see. I made 2 options here:

1. The week which contains the 1st of the month
2. The first full week (no day of previous month)

It can be "switched" in code using two booleans. It is now setted for the second option.

Feel free to ask for any question! ;)

```js
// Switches about what to display
// Use only one of the two to true.
var FIND_first_full_week = true;
var FIND_first_day_of_month = false;


$("#calendar").fullCalendar({

  viewRender: function(){
    var ShowWeek;
    var weeks = $(".fc-week");

    // Find the first day of the month
    if(FIND_first_day_of_month){
      for(i=0;i<weeks.length;i++){
        var days = weeks.eq(i).find(".fc-day-number");
        days.each(function(){
          if( $(this).html()=="1" && !$(this).parent().is(".fc-other-month") ){
            ShowWeek = i;
          }
        });
      }
    }
    
    // Find first full week of the month (no day in past month)
    if(FIND_first_full_week){
      for(i=0;i<weeks.length;i++){
        var firstFullWeek = false;
        var dayCount=0;

        var days = weeks.eq(i).find(".fc-day-number");
        days.each(function(){
          if(!firstFullWeek){
            if( !$(this).parent().is(".fc-other-month") ){
              dayCount++;
              if(dayCount==7){
                firstFullWeek = true;
                ShowWeek = i;
                i = weeks.length;
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
    
    // Fix FullCalendar display!
    setTimeout(function(){
      weeks.not(weeks.eq(ShowWeek)).css({"display":"none"});
      var weekHeight = weeks.height();
      $(".fc-day-grid-container").css({"height":weekHeight});
    },10);
  }
});
```

```css
/* Your CSS */
.fc td {
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
  border-top: 0 !important;
}

.fc-head {
  border-top: 1px solid black !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}
.fc-body{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: my friend i really appreciate the time you spent to help me out, you did exactly what i want and i salute you for it, thank you so much

Comment: No idea too... But you got it back ;) Your question was a good one, in my opinion.